# Matplotlib Bar graph -ValueError: shape mismatch:(x,y)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

While plotting the bar graph for number of attempt on x-aixs and time-taken on y-axis as per below code, getting Value error.Trace of error is included below.

```
import time as t
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

times=[];
mistakes=0;
input("press enter to continue")

while len(times)<5:
    start=t.time();
    word=input("Type the word==>")
    end=t.time();
    t_cal=end-start;

    times.append(t_cal)

    if(word.lower() != "programing"):
        mistakes+=1

    print("You mistake", str(mistakes)," Times. ")

    print("see your progress")
    t.sleep(5);

    x=[1,2,3,4,5]
    y=times

    plt.bar(x,y)

    grnd=["1","2","3","4","5"]
    plt.xticks(x,grnd)
    plt.xlabel("ur attempt")
    plt.ylabel("time in secconds")
    plt.title("ur typing speed")
    plt.show()
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-8cc693c6dda0> in <module>
     25     y=times
     26 
---> 27     plt.bar(x,y)
     28 
     29     grnd=["1","2","3","4","5"]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in bar(x, height, width, bottom, align, data, **kwargs)    2439     return gca().bar(    2440         x, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, align=align,
-> 2441         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)    2442     2443 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)    1597     def inner(ax, *args, data=None,
**kwargs):    1598         if data is None:
-> 1599             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)    1600     1601         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bar(self, x, height, width, bottom, align, **kwargs)    2372         x, height, width, y, linewidth = np.broadcast_arrays(    2373             # Make args iterable too.
-> 2374             np.atleast_1d(x), height, width, y, linewidth)    2375     2376         # Now that units have been converted, set the tick locations.

<__array_function__ internals> in broadcast_arrays(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in broadcast_arrays(*args, **kwargs)
    262     args = [np.array(_m, copy=False, subok=subok) for _m in args]
    263 
--> 264     shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
    265 
    266     if all(array.shape == shape for array in args):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in
_broadcast_shape(*args)
    189     # use the old-iterator because np.nditer does not handle size 0 arrays
    190     # consistently
--> 191     b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
    192     # unfortunately, it cannot handle 32 or more arguments directly
    193     for pos in range(32, len(args), 31):

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because as it says in trace ,at the second and consecutive runs values of x and y are/shall mis matching. You are trying to plot 2 or more values against 1. Arrange the values of x as per the values of Y.

> `x = np.arange(len(y)`

```
import time as t
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

times=[];
mistakes=0;
input("press enter to continue")

while len(times)<5:
    start=t.time();
    word=input("Type the word==>")
    end=t.time();
    t_cal=end-start;

    times.append(t_cal)

    if(word.lower() != "programing"):
        mistakes+=1

    print("You mistake", str(mistakes)," Times. ")

    print("see your progress")
    t.sleep(5);

    #x=[1,2,3,4,5]
    y=times
    x = np.arange(len(y))
    print("lenght of y is :",len(y))

    plt.bar(x,y)

    grnd=["1","2","3","4","5"]
    plt.xticks(x,grnd)
    plt.xlabel("ur attempt")
    plt.ylabel("time in secconds")
    plt.title("ur typing speed")
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]